# Live Photos and normal photos through PHAsset

Tags: swift, photos

I'm trying to have a collection of photo's displayed. to get these photo's, I'm using the `Photos` framework.

I was using the following code to get the photos:

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.sortDescriptors = [
    NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
]

images = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: options)
```

However, I'd also like to get Live Photo's (so a combination of both, Live Photo's would ideally just be the first still Frame.

Now I know you can get Live Photos like this:

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.sortDescriptors = [
    NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
]

options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(mediaSubtype & %d) != 0", PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoLive.rawValue)

images = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options)
```

However, I don't know how to make a combination of the two... Is there any way to do this, perhaps by creating two `NSPredicate`s?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how you get both Live Photos and still photos through `PHAsset`:

Step 1: Create a `NSPredicate` to detect normal photos:

```
let imagesPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)
```

Step 2: Create a `NSPredicate` to detect Live Photos:

```
let liveImagesPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(mediaSubtype & %d) != 0", PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoLive.rawValue)
```

Step 3: Combine both with a `NSCompoundPredicate`:

```
let compound = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [imagesPredicate, liveImagesPredicate])
```

Step 4: Assign the `NSCompoundPredicate` to your `PHFetchOptions`:

```
options.predicate = compound
```

Step 5: Enjoy!

So in your case:

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.sortDescriptors = [
    NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
]

// Get all still images
let imagesPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)

// Get all live photos
let liveImagesPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(mediaSubtype & %d) != 0", PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoLive.rawValue)

// Combine the two predicates into a statement that checks if the asset
// complies to one of the predicates.
options.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [imagesPredicate, liveImagesPredicate])
```

Comment: One remark, you should use andPredicateWithSubpredicates instead of orPredicateWithSubpredicates for successful Live Photo filtering.